# Change the spacing of tick marks on the axis of a plot?

Tags: r, plot

How can I change the spacing of tick marks on the axis of a plot?

What parameters should I use with base plot or with `rgl`?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519823/minor-tick-position-in-r for the size of ticks

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There are at least two ways for achieving this in **base graph** (my examples are for the x-axis, but work the same for the y-axis):

1. Use `par(xaxp  = c(x1, x2, n))` or `plot(..., xaxp  = c(x1, x2, n))` to define the position (`x1` & `x2`) of the extreme tick marks and the number of intervals between the tick marks (`n`). Accordingly, `n+1` is the number of tick marks drawn. (This works only if you use no logarithmic scale, for the behavior with logarithmic scales see `?par`.)
2. You can suppress the drawing of the axis altogether and add the tick marks later with `axis()`.
   To suppress the drawing of the axis use `plot(... , xaxt = "n")`.
   Then call `axis()` with `side`, `at`, and `labels`: `axis(side = 1, at = v1, labels = v2)`. With `side` referring to the side of the axis (1 = x-axis, 2 = y-axis), `v1` being a vector containing the position of the ticks (e.g., `c(1, 3, 5)` if your axis ranges from 0 to 6 and you want three marks), and `v2` a vector containing the labels for the specified tick marks (must be of same length as `v1`, e.g., `c("group a", "group b", "group c")`). See `?axis` and [my updated answer to a post on stats.stackexchange for an example of this method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/how-do-i-vertically-stack-two-graphs-with-the-same-x-scale-but-a-different-y-sca/1843#1843).

Comment: Is there a way to control how many decimal places R uses for numerical tick labels. I just tried labels=c(0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0) but in the graph the labels were 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, etc. Is there a way to get the same number of decimal places on all labels? I tried labels=round(seq(0,2,0.5),1) but the whole numbers still had no decimal places.

Comment: try functions `formatC` or `prettyNum`for creating character vectors to be passed to `labels`. E.g.: `formatC(seq(0,2,0.5), digits = 1, format = "f")`

Comment: +1 been looking for a while now to find this. Turns out though that `n` is actually number of tick marks `-1`. I wanted tick marks from `1` to `9` and had to set `xaxp = c(1, 9, 8)` or I would not get the desired result.

Comment: For me it doesn't work with `par(xaxp..)`. It works only when I put it inside the `plot(xaxp...)`

Answer (score 34):

With base graphics, the easiest way is to stop the plotting functions from drawing axes and then draw them yourself.

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 1, at = c(1,5,10))
axis(side = 2, at = c(1,3,7,10))
box()
```

Comment: Hello

I have datetime data on the x axis, (chron)
In my case I think it should be a better way than writing a line with let say 25 full dates.

What If I want the dates writen vertically on the x axis, I mean perpendicularly.

cheers

Comment: Look at graphics parameter `las` in ?par which can be added to a call to `axis()`, and which controls the orientation of the tick labels. E.g. `axis(side = 1, at = c(1,5,10), las = 2)`. You might want to investigate whether there is an `axis()` function for chron objects or consider using R's Date Time classes, which already have `axis()` functions (e.g. `axis.Date()` for the class '"Date"').

Answer (score 7):

I have a data set with Time as the x-axis, and Intensity as y-axis. I'd need to first delete all the default axes except the axes' labels with:

```
plot(Time,Intensity,axes=F)
```

Then I rebuild the plot's elements with:

```
box() # create a wrap around the points plotted
axis(labels=NA,side=1,tck=-0.015,at=c(seq(from=0,to=1000,by=100))) # labels = NA prevents the creation of the numbers and tick marks, tck is how long the tick mark is.
axis(labels=NA,side=2,tck=-0.015)
axis(lwd=0,side=1,line=-0.4,at=c(seq(from=0,to=1000,by=100))) # lwd option sets the tick mark to 0 length because tck already takes care of the mark
axis(lwd=0,line=-0.4,side=2,las=1) # las changes the direction of the number labels to horizontal instead of vertical.
```

So, `at = c(...)` specifies the collection of positions to put the tick marks. Here I'd like to put the marks at 0, 100, 200,..., 1000. `seq(from =...,to =...,by =...)` gives me the choice of limits and the increments.

Answer (score 3):

And if you don't want R to add decimals or zeros, you can stop it from drawing the x axis or the y axis or both using ...axt. Then, you can add your own ticks and labels:

```
plot(x, y, xaxt="n")
plot(x, y, yaxt="n")
axis(1 or 2, at=c(1, 5, 10), labels=c("First", "Second", "Third"))
```

Comment: Of course, you can programmatically turn this on and off with a variable `flag` with `yaxt=flag`  BUT the trick is if you want to standard labels on, then set `flag <- "s"` and if you don't want the standard labels then use `flag <- "n"`  (Adding this, because it took me a while to find "s")

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered the [Hmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package:

> Contains many functions useful for data analysis, high-level graphics, utility operations, functions for computing sample size and power, importing and annotating datasets, imputing missing values, advanced table making, variable clustering, character string manipulation, conversion of R objects to LaTeX and html code, and recoding variables.

```r
library(Hmisc)    
plot(...)
minor.tick(nx=10, ny=10) # make minor tick marks (without labels) every 10th
```