# Grid line consistent with ticks on axis

Tags: r, graph, gridlines

I am embarrassed to ask this simple question, but has been in kicking my mind for several days whenever I create a plot:

```
plot (x = 1:10, y = rnorm (10, 5, 2))
grid (10,10, lty = 6, col = "cornsilk2")
```

I want to position the grids right at where axis are labelled, i.e. at 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 in x axis and similarly 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 in y axis.

[image]

I want to automate the process as whenever the plot size changes the default label behaviour changes. See the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From `?grid` description of the `nx` and `ny` arguments:

> When NULL, as per default, the grid aligns with the tick marks on the 
>   corresponding default axis (i.e., tickmarks as computed by axTicks)

```
plot (x = 1:10, y = rnorm (10, 5, 2)) 
grid (NULL,NULL, lty = 6, col = "cornsilk2")
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the help files and -1 for myself for not understanding the help well...

Comment: This does not seem to work with timestamps on X axis. Any ideas?

Comment: @slovon I think you'll have to draw the grid manually in that case. The docs for `grid` say only that it will align with the ticks for the "default" axis, and clearly the datetime plot method is doing something different than what would be returned by `axTicks`.

Comment: @slovon If it helps, I think the tick mark locations are coming from `graphics:::axis.POSIXct`.

Comment: @slovon you should check this other question answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010161/align-grid-to-plot-ticks The `abline()` workaround works fine with time series objects.

Answer (score 24):

For reference, there is a way to control the grid and axes parameters directly from the plot() command, if we are not defining a custom tick interval:

```
plot(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10, 5, 2), xlim=c(1, 10), ylim=c(1, 10), panel.first=grid())
```

The plot.default() documentation gives more information about these parameters.

When using a custom ticks interval, the easiest is to draw the grid using abline:

```
plot(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10, 5, 2), xaxp=c(1, 10, 10), yaxp=c(1, 10, 10), axes=FALSE)
axis(1, 1:10)
axis(2, 1:10)
abline(h=1:10, v=1:10, col="gray", lty=3)
```

[image: grid example]

More information about custom tick intervals in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785089/r-change-the-spacing-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-of-a-plot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044066/align-x-axis-to-plot-for-consistent-use-with-grid) for grid alignment.

Answer (score 7):

For posterity, here is the long-winded way of doing it manually:

```
plot (x = 1:10, y = rnorm (10, 5, 2))
grid (lty = 6, col = "cornsilk2")

xaxp <- par("xaxp")
yaxp <- par("yaxp")

abline(v=seq(xaxp[1], xaxp[2], (xaxp[2]-xaxp[1])/xaxp[3]), lty=6, col = "cornsilk2")
abline(h=seq(yaxp[1], yaxp[2], (yaxp[2]-yaxp[1])/yaxp[3]), lty=6, col = "cornsilk2")
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010161/align-grid-to-plot-ticks) is much more straightforward, although you may dislike the lack of "free space" at each end of the axes.  In brief,

> The problem is that grid is putting nx grid lines in the user space,
>   but plot is adding 4% extra space on each side. You can take control
>   of this. Adding `xaxs="i", yaxs="i"` to your plot will turn off the
>   extra space. But then your upper right point will be cut off, so you
>   need to change the xlim and ylim values and change nx to match