# Align x-axis to plot for consistent use with grid

Tags: r, csv, histogram

I'm trying to build an histogram using data available from [here](http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/?f=%22radial%22%20IN%20detection). I'm using using the CSV version of this database to display the number of exoplantes discovered per year. A simple script would be

```
bulkdata <- read.csv('file.csv',head=1,sep=',')
pdf(file="yearcount.pdf",family="Times")
bins <- seq(min(bulkdata$discovered,na.rm=T),max(bulkdata$discovered,na.rm=T),by=1)
hist(bulkdata$discovered,breaks=bins,col='gray',ylab="Discovered",xlab="Year",main="",ylim=c(0,100),axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=seq(1989,2012,by=1))
axis(2, at=seq(0,100,by=10))
grid(nx=10)
hist(bulkdata$discovered,breaks=bins,col='gray',ylab="Discovered",xlab="Year",main="", add=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

The problem is that the `xaxis` **is not** aligned with the `0` point of the `yaxis`. This is a problem because the lines drawn by `grid()` *does not mean anything* because they are not aligned with the ticks! I tried to add in `axis(1, at=seq(1989,2012,by=1))` the option `line=-1` to correct but this way the axis is correctly *drawn* but the grid start *below* the axis. Maybe a non standard package is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?grid` says:

> If more fine tuning is required, use ‘abline(h = ., v = .)’
>        directly.

So here's a suggestion:

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
h <- hist(bulkdata$discovered,breaks=bins,
     col='gray',ylab="Discovered",xlab="Year",main="",
     ylim=c(0,100),axes=FALSE)
yrs <- 1989:2012
yvals <- seq(0,100,by=10)
axis(1, at=yrs)
axis(2, at=yvals)
abline(h=yvals,v=yrs,col="gray",lty=3)
hist(bulkdata$discovered,breaks=bins,
     col='gray',ylab="Discovered",xlab="Year",main="", add=TRUE)
```

I would consider making the grid lines a little bit sparser (e.g. every 5 years?)

[image]