# How do I change the numbering of the x axis in R to just 2 values?

Tags: r

I want to create a histogram from my data set of the frequency of students who have had broken bones. The values are either 0 or 1. 
I.E:

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[38] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[75] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[112] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
[149] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
[186] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
[223] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[260] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
[297] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
[334] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
[371] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

However the scale on the axis axis of the graph has increments of 0.2. I just want either 0 or 1 as the data is categorical. Would anyone please kindly tell me how to rectify this?

Comment: Either `plot(table(dat))` or `hist(dat,axes=FALSE); axis(side=2); axis(side=1,at=c(0,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a combination of assigning the appropriate values to the `breaks` argument and the `xaxp` argument in [?hist](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html).  Consider:

```
  # this just gives me your data:
my.data <- "
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
my.data <- unlist(strsplit(my.data, " "))
my.data <- gsub("\\n", "", my.data)
my.data <- as.numeric(my.data)

hist(my.data, breaks=c(-.5, .5, 1.5), xaxp=c(0,1,1))
```

`breaks` is used to define exactly 2 bins, and `xaxp` is used to change the number and placement of the tick marks on the x axis (for more on how `xaxp` works, see this excellent answer: [R, change the spacing of tick marks on the axis of a plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785089/r-change-the-spacing-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-of-a-plot/3785321#3785321))  Here is the resulting figure:

[image]

On a different note, it is not clear how informative a histogram is for data like this (or perhaps even ever, see: [assessing-approximate-distribution-of-data-based-on-a-histogram](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51718//51753#51753) on stats.SE). You might just was well try:

```
> table(my.data)
my.data
  0   1 
296  86
```

Comment: @BenBolker, that generates a rather ugly plot on my machine. Did you try it? Does it produce something nice for you?

Comment: I don't consider it *too* ugly -- `plot(table(my.data),lwd=10,col="gray",lend=2,las=1,bty="l")` is prettier ...