# decreasing the xaxis scale on R

Tags: r, scale, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram showing the number of individuals as a function of Depth as the picture below:
[image]

I am using this simple code:

```
hist(dataset,xlab="Depth",ylab="Number of individuals")
```

However i cannot manipulate with the xaxis values to show more details between the depths 0 and 100. I need to decrease the scale to show more detail.

Any solution?
Thank you

Comment: You might want to look here for some other insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785089/r-change-the-spacing-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-of-a-plot

Comment: Have you read the help text? `?hist`. Please study the `breaks` argument, and run through the examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the base plotting or with `ggplot2`.

Some sample data:

```
var <- sample(1:50,size=10000,replace=T)
dataset <- as.data.frame(var)
```

With the base plotting you could for example use:

```
hist(dataset, xlab="Depth", ylab="Number of individuals", breaks=10)
```

However, this doesn't solve your problem. With `ggplot2` you much more control about the appearance of your plot. Two examples:

```
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=var)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = "white", color = "black", binwidth = 10) +
  scale_x_continuous("Depth", limits=c(0,60), breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Number of individuals", limits=c(0,2100), breaks=c(0,400,800,1200,1600,2000)) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

```
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=var)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = "white", color = "black", binwidth = 5) +
  scale_x_continuous("Depth", limits=c(0,60), breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Number of individuals", limits=c(0,1100), breaks=c(0,250,500,750,1000)) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

With the `binwidth` parameter you can choose how much detail you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the number of breaks by setting the specific parameter e.g. :

```
dataset <- sample(1:50,size=10000,replace=T) # random data

hist(dataset,xlab="Depth",ylab="Number of individuals",breaks=100)
```

[image]

To change the labels on the xaxis, hust xaxp graphical parameter, e.g. :

```
dataset <- sample(1:50,size=10000,replace=T) # random data

nSep <- 5

f <- hist(dataset,xlab="Depth",ylab="Number of individuals", 
          xaxp = c(min(dataset), max(dataset), nSep))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the breaks, the problem is the numbers on the x axis :)