# minor.tick() position in R

Tags: r, plot

I've extensively searched for a solution without luck. I'd like to plot functions in the usual way (axes cross at (0,0)) using the default R plotting facilities. 
Setting the axes position to 0 as in the example below solve partially the problem. However when adding minor ticks the default position is retained resulting in the weird plot below.

```
plot.new() 
x <- seq(-10,10, 0.1)
f <- ((x+2)*(x-5))/((x-3)*(x+1))
plot.window(xlim=c(-10,10), ylim=c(-30,30))
axis(side=1, at=seq(-10,10,2), pos=0, las=0)
axis(2) 

library(Hmisc)
minor.tick(nx=5, ny=10, tick.ratio=0.5)
```

[image: Graph of plotted data]

Comment: you could try using ggplot2 (which should be imported with Hmisc) to: `qplot(x,f)+theme_bw()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to still use the `axis` function, and just specify the locations and size (`tck`) of the minor ticks.

```
plot.new() 
x <- seq(-10,10, 0.1)
f <- ((x+2)*(x-5))/((x-3)*(x+1))
plot.window(xlim=c(-10,10), ylim=c(-30,30))
axis(side=1, at=seq(-10,10,2), pos=0, las=0)
axis(side=1, at=seq(-10,10,0.5), pos=0, las=0, tck=-0.01, labels=FALSE)
axis(2)
```

This allows you to retain complete control over the plot.