# How do I add more date tick marks to X axis?

Tags: r, time-series, scatter-plot

I have some time series data that I am simply trying to plot in R. I would like the X-axis to have ticks for every month: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec

I am only able to get ticks for every other month.

Below is the code I use as well as the resulting plot:

```
plot(x2,y, col="red", main = "September 2009 Forecast - Bagger", 
     xlab = "Month", ylab="Sales")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdEba.png)

Comment: For some tips on manipulating the axis tick marks, see the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785089/r-change-the-spacing-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-of-a-plot).

Comment: `y <- rnorm(12);
x <- month.abb[1:12];

plot(y, col = "red", main = "My Title", xlab = "Month", ylab = "Sales", xaxt = "n") +
  axis(side = 1, at = 1:12, labels = x)`