# Making boxplot of grouped data

Tags: r, boxplot

I have 4 data frames consisting of data that looks like this (HuL1 is a bone):

```
   CEMETERY    SEX CONTEXT HuL1.L HuL1.R DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY
1  Medieval FEMALE    7172    285    286             0.3508772
2  Medieval FEMALE    8117    316    320             1.2658228
3  Medieval FEMALE   11090    309    312             0.9708738
14 Medieval FEMALE      19    326    332             1.8404908
15 Medieval FEMALE     349    310    313             0.9677419
16 Medieval FEMALE     383    319    322             0.9404389
```

and

```
        CEMETERY  SEX CONTEXT HuL1.L HuL1.R DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY
43 Post-Medieval MALE      20    317    321             1.2618297
44 Post-Medieval MALE      35    334    332            -0.5988024
45 Post-Medieval MALE      47    328    334             1.8292683
46 Post-Medieval MALE     143    332    332             0.0000000
47 Post-Medieval MALE     147    351    354             0.8547009
```

Each dataframe is a different length, and 2 consist of 'Medieval' data whilst the other 2 are 'Post-Medieval (A = medieval female data, B= medieval male data, C = post-medieval female data, D = post-medieval male data).
I have made a boxplot using

```
 x=boxplot(A$DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY,B$DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY,
C$DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY
,D$DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY,xlab="PERIOD",ylab="DIRECTIONAL ASYMMETRY 
(%)",names=c("Medieval","Medieval","Post-Medieval","Post-
Medieval"),col=c("turquoise","red","turquoise","red"))

legend(x="topleft",title="Sex",c("Female","Male"),fill=c("turquoise","red"))
```

[image]

but I want the 'Medieval' and 'Post-Medieval' plots to be grouped together, so the x-axis only says Medieval and Post-Medieval once.

Answer (score 0):

```
boxplot(A$DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY,B$DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY,
        C$DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY, D$DIRECTIONAL.ASYMMETRY, 
        xlab="PERIOD",ylab="DIRECTIONAL ASYMMETRY(%)",
        col=c("turquoise","red","turquoise","red"))

axis(side = 1, at = c(1.5, 3.5), labels = c("Medieval", "Post-Medieval"))

legend(x="topleft",title="Sex",c("Female","Male"),fill=c("turquoise","red"))
```

Comment: Thanks to @Henrik and his answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785089/change-the-spacing-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-of-a-plot