# Reduce the amount of y axis tick values in R (pirateplot)

Tags: r, plot, graph

Since I have updated R to version 3.5.2, my pirateplots (yarrr library) show more y axis ticks than before. Before they only showed ticks at full number values (1, 2, 3, etc., [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNRA3.png)), but now they also show ticks at .5 values (1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, etc., [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgZHl.png)). This is despite the fact that the data and scripts are exactly the same as before.

Do you know how I can remove the .5 value ticks and make the plots look like they looked before?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785089/change-the-spacing-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-of-a-plot) question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `yaxt.y` argument is what you're looking for as it allows you to override the default y axis construction.

Here's a plot using default arguments

```
pirateplot(weight ~ Diet, data = ChickWeight)
```

[Original plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QHfs.png)

Now with the `yaxt.y` argument

```
pirateplot(weight ~ Diet, data = ChickWeight, yaxt.y = seq(0, 400, 25))
```

[Second version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4sQ2.png)

You can also specify the grid line widths with `gl.lwd`:

```
pirateplot(weight ~ Diet, data = ChickWeight, yaxt.y = seq(0, 400, 25), gl.lwd = c(.5, 1.5), gl.col = "black")
```

[Third version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzPsv.png)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, the yaxt.y parameter doesn't seem to work for me. When I run your code (second version), I get the following error message:

`Error in pirateplot(weight ~ Diet, data = ChickWeight, yaxt.y = seq(0,  : 
  unused argument (yaxt.y = seq(0, 400, 25))`

I use yarrr version 0.1.6. Any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I just uninstalled and reinstalled Yarrr and now it works. I now use the latest developer version from GitHub. Perhaps that made the difference. Thanks for your help!